# Separability of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, when $1\leq p<\infty$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. The proof that the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a separable space, when $1\leq p<\infty$, is usually done by defining an isometry between $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $L^p(\Omega)\times L^p(\Omega)^N$. I completely understand the proof (see for example Brezis' book - Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations for a reference or this link: [$W^{1,p}$ is separable for $1\leq p<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545051/w1-p-is-separable-for-1-leq-p-infty)).

We know that any subset of a separable metric space is separable as well as any linear subspace of a separable Banach space is separable.

My question is: Why cannot we say, directly, that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a separable space as a linear subspace of the separable space $L^p(\Omega)$? Is there any problem with this reasoning or, maybe, the usual proof is just done in order to learn a new technique in the work with these spaces?

Comment: if i recall correctly, the isometry also establishes that $W^{1,p}$ is Banach

Comment: I think this is the problem: your reasoning would prove that $W^{1,p}$ is separable in the $L^p$ topology. However the $W^{1,p}$ topology is not the same as the subspace topology inherited from $L^p$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor No really. It's possible to prove the completeness by the Cauchy classical approach.

Comment: @User8128 Oh, yes. You are right. The topology in $W^{1,p}$ differ from the subspace topology, and this is why we use the isometry.